# Rails REST doesn't show/load the right page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Basically I created a controller, model and view for subjects. Basically I have 6 actions inside my controller and set up a REST inside my routes file to route the right file.

When I entered, http://localhost:3000/subjects/index it shows me the view for show.html.erb instead of the index.html.erb

Here's what my subject controller looks like:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subjects = Subject.sorted
  end
```

And here's the content of my index.html.erb file.

```
<% @page_title = "All Subjects" %>

<div class="subjects index">
<h2>Subjects</h2>

<%= link_to("Add New Subject", new_subject_path, :class => "action_new") %>

<table class="listing" summary="Subject list" border="1">
<tr class="header">
<th>#</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Visible</th>
<th>Pages</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= subject.position %> </td>
  <td><%= subject.name %> </td>
  <td class="center"><%= status_tag(subject.visible) %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %> </td>
  <td class="actions">
    <%= link_to("View Pages", pages_path(:subject_id => subject.id), :class => 'action show') %>
    <%= link_to("Show", subject_path(subject), :class => 'action show') %>
    <%= link_to("Edit", edit_subject_path(subject), :class => 'action edit') %>
    <%= link_to("Delete", delete_subject_path(subject), :class => 'action delete') %>
  <td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <table>
</div>
```

Also here's what I set up on my routes:

```
  resources :subjects do
    member do
      get :delete
    end
  end
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: in order you access the index page, you need to hit the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/subjects
```

Obviously, it will be with `GET`

The reason why you got the error is: since, anything of the format `subjects/:id` will take you to the `show` action within `SubjectsController`, so Rails interprets `subjects/index` as you are trying to access the page `subjects/:id` with `index` as `id` of the subject. Here's nothing wrong with Rails, since in RESTful web services, you access the index page by ONLY using the plural name of the resource, like in your case `http://localhost:3000/subjects`